# Razor page download function results in 403 Forbidden

Tags: asp.net, .net, razor-pages

I have this simple download function in my Razor Page:

```
public FileResult OnGetDownloadFile(string fileName, string Username)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(@"C:\DownloadTool\Downloads\", Username, fileName);
    byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);

    return File(bytes, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
}
```

When this is used i get the error

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

The IIS User has read-permissions on C:\DownloadTool\Downloads.
It works in my development environment but not on the IIS-Server itself.
The Get-parameters are passed correctly.

Anyone got an idea what to do?